# what should the mode_t of a root directory be when creating a new linux file system?

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

I am developing a new linux file system as part of a homework assignment.

What should the root directory (of my filesystem) file mode (mode_t) be?

Comment: On an existing system, try `ls -ld /` and you'd get `drwxr-xr-x`, which is `755`

Comment: Either `755` or even `555` — if `root` owns the file system, then `root` can create files or directories even without explicit user-write permission.  Occasionally, you might find `775`; you should never, never, never use `777`.